# Invoke 'Open' Dialog from Windows Desktop

Tags: windows, function, dll, vbscript, windows-xp

Is there some way I can programmatically (in VBS) OR by using CMD/RUN open the 'Open' dialog that contains the places bar and a browser but without opening say notepad or MSpaint?

http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC354177.jpg

I'd like to use this on the desktop itself, it would be really cool if there was a DLL I can just use instead of having  a VBS file but if not i'm sure its possible in VBS.

I'm busy searching where the actual open dialog box comes from, it should come from some DLL file somewhere.

I might even consider stopping the windows shell from opening all together and just using this open window as the shell on some computers.

Regards, Rocklore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Windows are you on?

`"UserAccounts.CommonDialog"` was the way to do this in XP. But it no longer exists in Windows 7. You may be able to use some of the flags available for the `BrowseForFolder()` method to make it look like a file open dialog. See [this](http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.com/2012/08/windows-7-replacement-for.html) page for an example.

**XP Edit:**

Here's an XP example using `UserAccounts.CommonDialog`.

```
With CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog")

    .InitialDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    .Filter = "All Files|*.*"

    ' Show the dialog. If [Open] is clicked, save the name of the selected file...
    If .ShowOpen Then strFile = .FileName

End With
```

Comment: I;m using windows XP pro

Comment: @rocklore OK, I've updated my answer to show an XP example using `UserAccounts.CommonDialog`.

Comment: Awesome! If you think this answer will help others, feel free to accept it.

Comment: How do I do that again? also how can I have it so if I hit enter or click OK it opens the file , currently it just closes the box when I click a file

Comment: You have to right click the item and choose Open. Default command in file selection dialogs is Select. There are many ways to do similar things.